# Conservation of Charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, conservation-laws, charge, universe

We know that universe is all about charge conservation mass conservation and energy conservation. Charge on a system can be measured by comparing it with charge on a standard body, positive and negative are associated with charge on the basic of attractive or repulsive properties. My question is that is the total positive or the total negative charge of the universe is constant or not?

In a beta decay neutron converts to proton and fresh electron the charge however remains zero

In case of alternating current the charge is constant and only the direction of current changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is that is the total positive or the total negative charge of the universe is constant or not?

This question is worded a little strangely. The total positive charge would be $n_+ e$ where $n_+$ is the number of protons and other such charged particles. The total negative charge would be $-n_- e$ where $n_-$ is the number of electrons and other such charged particles. Neither of these quantities is constant. Only their sum is constant $(n_+ - n_-) e$ as charges are always created in pairs, one positive and one negative.

Comment: I asked whether the total positive/negative charge of the universe remains constant or not. We know that overall net charge remains constant but i am specifically talking about net positive or net negative charge, further elaborating that sum of all positive charges present in the universe remains constant or not.

Comment: @Sarthak yes, I understood that and explicitly answered it: “Neither of these quantities is constant”

Answer (score 0):

Charge conservation is the principle that the total electric charge in an isolated system never changes. The net quantity of electric charge, the amount of positive charge minus the amount of negative charge in the universe, is always conserved.

Reference : [Charge Conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation)

Edit: The positive and negative charge separately is not conserved. The process like Pair production where
$$\gamma \rightarrow e^+ +  \ e^-$$
a gamma photon can produce an electron and positron lead to total charge conservation but not totally positive (or total negative ) charge conservation.

Comment: I asked whether the total positive/negative charge of the universe remains constant or not. We know that overall net charge remains constant but i am specifically talking about net positive or net negative charge, further elaborating that sum of all positive charges present in the universe remains constant or not.

Comment: See the edit! I have added a little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly better practice to refer to "an isolated system" rather than "the universe", but you can suppose that the isolated system is huge (e.g. many galaxy clusters) and then the possible transfer of charge at its boundary will only have a negligible influence on ordinary timescales.

In any case, if a system is truly isolated then its total charge $Q$ stays constant. This total might be the sum of two parts, $Q = Q_1 + Q_2$ and the two parts do not need to be constant. For example, in pair creation you get one extra negative and one extra positive charge, but the total stays constant.

Comment: I asked whether the total positive/negative charge of the universe remains constant or not. We know that overall net charge remains constant but i am specifically talking about net positive or net negative charge, further elaborating that sum of all positive charges present in the universe remains constant or not.

Comment: @Sarthak yes; that is covered in the second paragraph of my answer. If $Q_1$ is the positive and $Q_2$ the negative charge, then neither is constant. For example, during pair creation both of them change by $e$ (the electronic charge).

Answer (score 0):

The total positive charge of the universe is not constant. You have already given an example of a process that does not conserve positive charge. In beta decay the positive charge of the outputs ($+1e$) is greater than the positive charge of the inputs ($0$). Similarly, beta decay does not conserve total negative charge either. The quantity that *is* conserved in all processes (as far as we know) is the net charge.

Since you seem to already know all this, I think there may be some subtle point in your question that neither I nor the other answerers here are getting. You talk about “net positive charge” and “net negative charge” as if they mean something different from “overall net charge”. Can you explain what you think is the difference ?